# A typical calling constructor from another constructor, but gives me an error

Tags: c#

While trying to make a regular constructor to constructor call in the same class :

```
    public Equation(OrdinaryEquations equation, 
                    double xTranslation,
                    double yTranslation, 
                    double rotationAngle)
      : this( (equation == OrdinaryEquations.SecondOrder) ? new EquationFunction(SecondOrderEquation) : new EquationFunction(ThirdOrderEquation), 
        xTranslation, yTranslation, rotationAngle){}
```

OrdinaryEquations is enumeration

EquationFunction is a delegate

I get this error : 
" An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"
foreach :  " new EquationFunction(SecondOrderEquation)" and  "new EquationFunction(ThirdOrderEquation)"
which sounds like when I try to access object data from static method

the other constructor sig. :

```
public Equation(EquationFunction equation, double xTranslation, double yTranslation, double rotationAngle){}
```

Is there something I'm missing here ? I can't figure out what to do !!

P.S I removed the conditional operator and made it a normal object initialization but gave the same error

Comment: What is "SecondOrderEquation", as in "new EquationFunction(SecondOrderEquation)"?

Comment: Can you give us the code to EquationFunction

Comment: SecondOrderEquation is a method
EquationFunction is a delegate : public delegate double EquationFunction(double value);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume "SecondOrderEquation" is a method name in your class "Equation".
The usage of "SecondOrderEquation" refers to this.SecondOrderEquation which needs a instance of type "Equation" to be a context.

To fix it, you can try to make "SecondOrderEquation" and "ThirdOrderEquation" to be static methods.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your inline if statement in the constructor call.

Generally speaking this type of object construction is a bit of a code smell.

Perhaps you ought to consider creating a factory method instead?

Answer (score 0):

> new EquationFunction(SecondOrderEquation)

I do not know what SecondOrderEquation, but it seems to be a type.. Did you mean typeof(SecondOrderEquation)?

Comment: I don't think so - the signature of the second constructor has a variable of type `EquationFunction` as the first argument.